# How do I make cubes a specific color using python code for Maya

Tags: python, maya

I have cubes being created based on specific vertex locations but I need to know how to make these cubes red, via a python script and not having to select the cubes in Maya and manually making them red.

Comment: The usual practice is to include at least some stab at working code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: oh, and while you're at it you'll get a better answer if you're clear on how you want them colored... do you want a red _material_? a red _vert color_? red in the outliner? Wireframe color?

Comment: def placement(points):
        
    inside_of_mesh = []
    outside_of_mesh = []
    
    for i in range (0,len(points)):
        cmds.spaceLocator(p=points[i])
        print test_if_inside_mesh(point=points[i])
    
        if test_if_inside_mesh(point=points[i]):
            inside_of_mesh.append(points[i])
            
            cmds.polyCube(sx=1,sy=1,sz=1)
            cmds.xform(t=points[i])
            cmds.polyColorPerVertex( rgb=(0.8, 0.0, 0.0) )

Comment: and I just need the materials to be colored red, the specific on material doesn't matter, just something red in color

Comment: @Lynn, please don't put code in comments. It's very hard to read (this is especially true of Python code, where formatting is semantically important). Instead, [edit] your question and paste it there. Select the code block and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button to format it as code.

Answer (score 2):

to assign a material in maya you need to get the associated materials's shading group, which in Maya is a `shadingEngine` node.  They you use the sets command with that as an argument.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# assign shader to objects.  objects can be a single object or a list of objects
def assign_shader(shader, objects):
    # get the shadingGroup with listConnections
    shading_group = cmds.listConnections(shader, type='shadingEngine')[-1]
    # use `sets` to force the objects into the shading group
    cmds.sets(objects, fe=shading_group)

# examples
# assign_shader('lambert1', 'pCube1')
# assign_shader('lambert1', ['pCube1', 'pCube2'])
```

You can manually make a red material and call it anything you want then assign it this way. If you want to create the shader programmatically, it's:

```
 new_shader = cmds.shadingNode('lambert', asShader=True, name='yournamehere')
 new_sg = cmds.sets(renderable=True, noSurfaceShader=True, empty=True)
 cmds.connectAttr(new_shader + '.outColor', new_sg + ".surfaceShader", force=True)
```

You'd then feed `new_shader` into `assign_shader`

If all you care about is a simple color, you should use the `lambert` shader as above. To set the color of a lambert it's just

```
cmds.setAttr('your_lambert_here' + ".color", 1,0,0)
```